# If the props for a child component are unchanged, does React still re-render it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have the following pairing of parent and child components in React:

```
var ChildComponent = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps: function(){
        return {
            a: 'a',
            b: 'b',
            c: 'c'
        }
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            /* jshint ignore:start */
            <div className={'child' + (this.props.b ? ' modifierClass' : '')} something={this.props.a}>
                {this.props.c}
            </div>
            /* jshint ignore:end */
        );
    }
});


var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function(){
        //After 10 seconds, change a property that DOES NOT affect the child component, and force an update
        setTimeout(function(){
            this.setState({foo: 'quux'});
            this.forceUpdate();
        }.bind(this), 10000);
    }

    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            foo: 'bar',
            a: 1,
            b: 2,
            c: 3
        }
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            /* jshint ignore:start */
            <div className="parent">
                <ChildComponent a={this.props.a} b={this.props.b} c={this.props.c}/>
            </div>
            /* jshint ignore:end */
        );
    }
});


React.render(
    /* jshint ignore:start */
    <ParentComponent />, 
    /* jshint ignore:end */
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
);
```

When I do the `forceUpdate`, since none of the props that were passed to the `ChildComponent` changed, will React try to re-render it?  What if I have 1000 such children, etc?

What I'm worried about is a situation where I have a very deep `ChildComponent` containing a whole massive tree of descendant components, but I only want to enact some relatively cosmetic changes on the `ParentComponent`.  Is there any way to get React to update only the parent, without trying to re-render the children as well?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When React re-renders `ParentComponent` it will automatically re-render `ChildComponent`. The only way to get around is to implement `shouldComponentUpdate` in the `ChildComponent`. You should compare `this.props.a`, `this.props.b` and `this.props.c` and `ChildComponents` own state to decide to re-render or not. If you are using immutable data than you can just compare previous and next state and props using strict equality `===`.

There are a few thing to note with your code

1. You dont need to `forceUpdate` when you `setState`. React automatically does it for you.
2. You probably meant:

   `<ChildComponent a={this.props.a} b={this.props.b} c={this.props.c}/>`

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I was looking for!  Follow up question - is there any way to update the parent component while still allowing `shouldComponentUpdate` to execute on the children?  Currently, when my Backbone model emits a `change` event, my `ParentComponent` executes a `forceUpdate`.  Is there anything I can do to "force" an update, but still invoke `shouldComponentUpdate` on the children?

Comment: [React docs beg to differ](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate).  When using `forceUpdate`, it says that `shouldComponentUpdate` is ignored.

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate` is called automatically on the `ChildComponent`, you dont have to do anything about it. `forceUpdate` skips the `shouldComponentUpdate` method of `ParentComponent`.

Comment: here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p7v59d0r/. You can look at the logs on the console.

Comment: Ah, gotcha!  Thanks for the fiddle too!