# Why does React rerender a child if its props remain unchanged?

Tags: reactjs

The answer from this question makes sense: [If the props for a child component are unchanged, does React still re-render it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361252/if-the-props-for-a-child-component-are-unchanged-does-react-still-re-render-it?newreg=0eecfff7d32c4c14b9143e81bcd8b5b4) and I also made a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/yaeljiao/pen/NgyqeJ?editors=0011) to verify it.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  console.log(nextProps.test === this.props.test);
  console.log('shouldComponentUpdate');
  return true;
}
```

But one statement on React's website is that:

> `shouldComponentUpdate()` is invoked before rendering when new props or state are being received.

But in reality, `shouldComponentUpdate()` is still invoked even if the props and state for a child component remain unchanged. Is there some mistake in the offical statement, or I have misunderstood it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the parent component `Clock` is being rerendered every second, the `Child` component also gets rerendered too. This is because `Clock` rerenders completely whenever a state update happens, as the clock moving forward a second. Thus, since `Child` is part of `Clock`, it too get rerendered.

The quote from the React documentation is correct:

> `shouldComponentUpdate()` is invoked before rendering when new props or state are being received.

Whenever `Child` is rerendered, the prop `test` is received again and again after every second the `Clock` is rerendered. That's what 'new props or state' is referring to here, not necessarily that it's getting different, unique props. Thus, `shouldComponentUpdate` is called every time the `Child` is rerendered because the prop `test` is given to the `Child` on each rerender.

Comment: thanks! My misunderstood to 'new props or state'. I used to suppose 'new updated props or state'. XD